# Bootstrap column and row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap columns which allows a maximum of 12.  I need two different divs in one row, one having 12 cols and the other 4.  I need the one of 4 cols to appear on the one of 12. Means both of divs will be in the same row. Please how do I achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't describing your issue well at all. What have you actually tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So sorry about that. I'd try some of the options provided,  I'm sure I'd get it right.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can split main container to two columns, for example 50/50 and inside they you can put next columns.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6>
    <div class="col-md-3></div>
    <div class="col-md-3></div>
    <div class="col-md-3></div>
    <div class="col-md-3></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
    <div class="col-md-1></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where did the rows go?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by following the below mentioned steps:

1. Go to [Customize Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) page.
2. Increase the value of `@grid-columns` variable from `12` to `16`.
3. Compile and Download the modified css.

And then you will be able to use 16 columns in a row instead of 12 as shown below.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-4"></div>
</div>
```